# Date columns from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have different data type columns in my table but from those columns i want a list of only those columns whose data type is date.

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A synonym does not have columns, the table it refers to has. So you might use this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS atc
JOIN ALL_SYNONYMS als ON atc.table_name = als.table_name
WHERE als.OWNER IN (USER, 'PUBLIC') AND DATA_TYPE = 'DATE';
ORDER BY atc.COLUMN_ID
```

Use `Dynamic SQL`

```
DECLARE Cols NVARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE SQL_Stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)  

Cols := SELECT listagg(COLUMN_NAME , ', ') within group (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME)  
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS atc
JOIN ALL_SYNONYMS als ON atc.table_name = als.table_name
WHERE als.OWNER IN (USER, 'PUBLIC') AND DATA_TYPE = 'DATE';
ORDER BY atc.COLUMN_ID

SQL_Stmt := 'SELECT '+ Cols +' FROM Projects'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_Stmt
```

Comment: i  have added a line als.SYNONYM_NAME = ' ' in the where clause to get the columns from the specific synonym

Answer (score 1):

Query `user_tab_columns`, e.g.

```
SQL> select column_name
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'EMP'
  4    and data_type = 'DATE';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
HIREDATE

SQL>
```

If you work with synonyms, no problem either: join `user_synonyms` and `user_tab_columns`.

```
SQL> create synonym syn_emp for emp;

Synonym created.

SQL> select c.column_name
  2  from user_tab_columns c join user_synonyms s on s.table_name = c.table_name
  3  where s.synonym_name = 'SYN_EMP'
  4    and c.data_type = 'DATE';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
HIREDATE

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, forgot to mention that i am dealing with synonyms here, when use the above query against the synonym i am getting empty result.

Comment: I edited my answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.